# Returning paragraph breaks with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of comments in my database that returns the following entries:

[image]

The comment field is a TEXT which includes paragraph breaks. **My question is**: how do I return these breaks inside Knockout?

```
<p data-bind="text: comment"></p>
```

will return

```
<p data-bind="text: comment">paragraph 1

paragraph 2

paragraph 3</p>
```

I also tried the `html` binding, but that only seems to wrap HTML around the returned value, not inside it. So is there a way to add a `</p> <p>` between the breaks without having to resort to `<pre>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a computed observable to format the text. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/badsyntax/dcVZq/

I split the text on the paragraph character, then join it with opening and closing `<p>` tags:

`'<p>' + this.text().split('&para;').join('</p><p>') + '</p>';`